# Creating editable CrawlSpider rules in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I've been trying to create a simple Scrapy CrawlSpider script that can be changed easily, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the link extractor Rules to work properly.

Here is my code:

```
class LernaSpider(CrawlSpider):
"""Our ad-hoc spider"""

name = "lerna"

def __init__(self, url, allow_follow='.*', deny_follow='', allow_extraction='.*', deny_extraction=''):
    parsed_url = urlparse(url)
    domain = str(parsed_url.netloc)
    self.allowed_domains = [domain]
    self.start_urls = [url]
    self.rules = (
        # Extract links
        # and follow links from them (since no callback means follow=True by default).
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(allow_follow, ), deny=(deny_follow, ))),

        # Extract links and parse them with the spider's method parse_item
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(allow_extraction, ), deny=(deny_extraction, )), callback='parse_item'),
    )

    super(LernaSpider, self).__init__()

def parse_item(self, response):

    print 'Crawling... %s' % response.url
    # more stuff here
```

I have this code, but I can never get the allow/deny rules to work properly and I don't really get why. Is leaving the empty strings causing it to deny everything? I thought since it was a RE it would only do a blanket denial if I input '.*' or whatever.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you instantiating the spider yourself?  something like:

```
spider = LernaSpider('http://example.com')
```

because otherwise if you are running `$scrapy crawl lerna` from the command line you are incorrectly using url as the first parameter in the constructor (should be name) and also you are not passing it on to the super.  Maybe try this:

```
class LernaSpider(CrawlSpider):
    """Our ad-hoc spider"""

    name = "lerna"

    def __init__(self, name=None, url=url, allow_follow='.*', deny_follow='', allow_extraction='.*', deny_extraction='', **kw):
        parsed_url = urlparse(url)
        domain = str(parsed_url.netloc)
        self.allowed_domains = [domain]
        self.start_urls = [url]
        self.rules = (
            # Extract links
            # and follow links from them (since no callback means follow=True by default).
            Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=allow_follow, deny=deny_follow)),

            # Extract links and parse them with the spider's method parse_item
            Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=allow_extraction, deny=deny_extraction), callback='parse_item'),
        )
        super(LernaSpider, self).__init__(name, **kw)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print 'Crawling... %s' % response.url
        # more stuff here
```

The regex stuff looks, fine: empty values allow all and deny none.

Comment: Yes, I am instantiating the spider myself within a script. Code is like, crawler = CrawlerProcess(settings)
spider = LernaSpider(url)
crawler.crawl(spider)

There's more stuff to it than that, obviously, but that's the short version.

Comment: I just tried changing allow=(allow_extraction) to allow=allow_extraction and it worked! Not 100% sure why, but thanks for giving me something to work from. :)

Comment: @steven almeroth, can i change the rules after crawl? something like `SpiderName.rules = new_rules` ??

Comment: @wolfgang why don't you ask a new question?  You might get a better answer.  You can change the rules but you would have to handle them with custom code because Scrapy only compiles them upon instantiation into `_rules`.